# app.use() requires a middleware function error

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In a nodejs project I'm getting this error : 'app.use() requires a middleware function error at the line 7 of this file :

```
const Router = require('./route');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(Router);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

and I really don't get why I'm getting this error.
here are the routes files

```
const ProduitRouter = require('./produit');
const router = require("express").Router();

router.use("/produit", ProduitRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

---

```
const ProduitControleur = require("../controleur/produitDB");
const Router = require("express-promise-router");
const router = new Router;

//const router = require("express").Router();

router.get('/:id', ProduitControleur.getProduit);
router.post('/', ProduitControleur.postProduit);
router.patch('/', ProduitControleur.updateProduit);
router.delete('/', ProduitControleur.deleteProduit);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you importing your router?

Comment: Yes I am, forgot to copy this line sorry

Comment: Are you importing from the right file?

Comment: `const router = new Router;` is not correct.  It should be `const router = Router();`.  You don't use `new` with Routers, either from `Express` or from `express-promise-router`.

Comment: I changed it in my code but still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const http = require('http');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

require('./routes')(app); // path of file in which all your routes are defined.



module.exports = app;
```

in router file where all routes are define.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('path of controller');


router.post('/upload/file', verifyToken, controller .functionName);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

As I can see, there is no imports for Router file

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: `app.use(express.json());` - in this line use pass 'express.json()' which imported before at the top like 'const express = require('express');'


`app.use(Router);` - but here you trying to use variable 'Router' that is not exist

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I forgot to copy this line, I just modified my post